# What algorithm is Mathematica using for FirstPassageTimeDistribution[]?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details

What algorithm is *Mathematica* 9 using for `FirstPassageTimeDistribution[]`?  Is it attempting to use `PseudoInverse[]` on the Laplacian of the graph underlying the discrete Markov process?

Comment: I suggest you write to support@wolfram.com and ask.  They will probably give you all the details you need (e.g. the paper reference).

Answer (score 2):

According to Wolfram Support:

> First passage time distribution is defined by its characteristic function which is computed from the underlying Markov chain. The implementation has been based on a variety of references, but mostly based on the book by W.J. Steward, "Probability, Markov Chains, Queues and Simulation" which was found to be very comprehensive.